# ECS draining with daemon tasks and non-daemon tasks, stoppingAt vs stoppedAt

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Let's say i have tasks A to C, C being a daemon tasks with a metrics collector role.

When I drain the instance

- A stoppedAt 0:01
- C stoppedAt 0:04
- B stoppedAt 0:08

My understanding is daemon tasks are stopped last

the stoppingAt times though are different

- A stoppingAt 0:01
- B stoppingAt 0:02
- C stoppingAt 0:03

Looking at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/graceful-shutdowns-with-ecs/B entered a deregistration delay

So my question is from the time the daemon tasks stopped to B transitioning to a stopped state, were there in-flight requests that may have gotten through that C wasn't able to collect data for?